# How do I get the value of the $ (this) .children inner element attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cheerio

There is such a library code  [Cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio):

```
let outputTableBody = $('.box.table-quotes table.table tr').each(function(i, elem) {
   let expression = $(this).children('td:nth-child(1)').text();


   if(expression == companyNameArray[ExchangeNameParse]){
     $(this).children('td').each(function(i, elem) {
       if( i == 1 ){
         // do something
         }
       })
     }
})
```

In this example, I can pull out the text value of the `td` elements - regardless of whether there are additional parents there or not - the text will still be extracted correctly.

Question:
If such a tag (`td`) contains a child tag `a` - how can I extract the value of its `href` attribute in this construction?

Comment: `$(this).children('a').attr('href')`

Comment: that doesn't worked:
http://joxi.ru/D2PgJPYhJOOZym

Comment: Print `$(this).children('a')` instead.

Comment: http://joxi.ru/vAWWbPKIOwwxdA
I don't know what should I do with it )

Comment: `$(this).find('a').attr('href')`

Comment: it worked.......

Comment: @hoangdv please add this as an answer.  OP Make sure you accept his answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.find` method to get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector  - `a` in this case:

```
...
const link = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
...
```